# what is the significance of "tui"

Tags: linux, centos

Both `system-config-network` and `system-config-network-tui` seem to do the same thing.  I've come across other similar commands as well.  What is the significance of "tui"?  Should it always be included in the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the non-tui version is meant to run as a gnome X windows application.  Not all of the scripts are like this, unfortunately.  But if there is a tui version, that would force text mode in case you do not want the gnome version.

Comment: "TUI" thus being short for "Text(ual) UI".